# Oracle Unique Constraint based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have the following unique constraint

```
dup_Checklist_QNum UNIQUE (QUESTION_NO, IS_ACTIVE)
```

I am trying to prevent two questions having the same question number while being active (IS_ACTIVE value = 1).

All seemed fine until I had to rev a question for the second time.

```
QUESTION_NO=1, TEXT="Have you..", REV=1, IS_ACTIVE=0  
QUESTION_NO=1, TEXT="Have you..", REV=2, IS_ACTIVE=0  <-- This should be ok but constraint was violated
QUESTION_NO=1, TEXT="Have you..", REV=3, IS_ACTIVE=1
QUESTION_NO=1, TEXT="Have you..", REV=3, IS_ACTIVE=1 <-- This should be throw constraint exception
```

I need the constraint to only apply when IS_ACTIVE=1

Comment: I guess as a work around, I could just deactivate questions by using a unique number, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc... Provided my application only cares when the value is 1, and ignores all other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional unique constraint in oracle db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317774/conditional-unique-constraint-in-oracle-db)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a unique function-based index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_dup_active
    ON <<table name>>( CASE WHEN is_active = 1
                            THEN question_no
                            ELSE NULL
                        END );
```

This takes advantage of the fact that Oracle b-tree indexes do not store data where the leaf block data would be entirely NULL.

Comment: I wonder when Oracle finally gives us less clumsy partial indexes by allowing a WHERE clause for the CREATE INDEX.

Comment: I have a similar case but the unique constraint needs to be on 2 columns, I'm trying to wrap my head around the syntax