# MySQL Unique Constraint based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique-constraint, mysql-5.7

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
  id     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  code   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  active BIT          NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

**Problem:**

I want to add a unique constraint on `code` column. But it should be applied only if `active` is set to `true` (uniqueness should be checked only among active records). There can be many records with `active` = `false` and the same `code` so I can't use constraint on multiple columns.

**What I tried:**

I haven't found any references in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) proving that such constraint is possible, but I know it is possible in [other databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335947/2065796) using unique function-based indexes.

Of course I can write a trigger that will check the invariant on every add/update operation, but I hope there is more efficient solution.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.15.

Comment: This simply isn't possible in MySQL, I'm afraid.  The closest you could *perhaps* come is to have a uniquely constrained column which is nullable (replacing the active field).  When `NULL` - it's "inactive", when anything other than `NULL` - it has to be unique.  Otherwise read/write to the table through a stored procedure or do something inelegant with triggers.

Comment: Possibly there's something more elegant, but it'd require us knowing the bigger picture (that is to say - the overall problem you're trying to solve).  Could you update your question with the Big Picture(TM)?

Answer (score 5):

This simply isn't possible in MySQL, I'm afraid.

I have come "close" to solving this in the past by having a uniquely constrained column which is nullable (replacing both the `active` and `code` fields).  When `NULL` - it's "inactive", when anything other than `NULL` - it has to be unique.

But that doesn't precisely solve the problem you're asking.  (Perhaps something better can be suggested if you could update your question to include the bigger picture?)

Otherwise read/write to the table through a stored procedure or - as you've suggested yourself - do something inelegant with triggers.

Comment: I can't set `code` to `NULL` for inactive records - it is still business valuable information (for instance the record could later be moved back to active state)

Comment: Ah OK - fair enough.  Without seeing the bigger picture then, I think you're probably stuck having a transactionally safe procedure for read/writing to the table which updates a separate column with a unique constraint.  Unfortunately as good as MySQL is, it doesn't have a lot of functionality that some of the other DBMSes do... :-)

Comment: That's sad true. Probably MySQL wasn't the best choice we made, but unfortunately it is too late to change. This is already the 4th important feature in my list which is missing in MySQL but present in other free DBs. On the other hand who knows, may be there might be some other important features present in MySQL and missing in those DBs.

Comment: I like to think of MySQL as "having everything someone needs from a DBMS ... but lacking a ton of things someone wants."  It's a superb platform, with transactional safety, incredible performance, replication, permissions, etc.  But for a lot of situations you have to work harder to get to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need use `CHECK` clause but it MySQL don't support it. From doc:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 13.1.18, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”. The reason for accepting but ignoring syntax clauses is for compatibility, to make it easier to port code from other SQL servers, and to run applications that create tables with references.

So you can do this only by check data on application level or insert/update rows in this table by stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I sorry this does not really a direct answer your question but:

Maybe you are better off with a different table design? The fact that something you want to do is not supported by your RDBMS is always a strong evidence that you are using it wrong.

Have you thought about creating a dept and an dept_history table, dept containing only the active records? That would solve your problem with the unique constraint.

Comment: It is overhead. The fact that MySQL doesn't support `CHECK` clause doesn't mean that DB design is wrong - almost all other DB provides do support this.

Comment: Just offering an alternative approach here. I can´t judge you DB-Design, as I don´t know it, but you are certainly wanting to use MySQL (The RDBMS) beyond its capabilities. What kind of overhead do you think does the check-clause introduce into an RDBMS that does support it?

Comment: Of course it is trade-off. There were reasons for sure. Bot not having such feature out of the box shifts the responsibility to a developer, who will for sure implement it in a less efficient way. I'd like to have the feature with all it's overheads/consequences rather than implement it by myself.