# Oracle - Add constraint on table not allow more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple table **driver**

```
 id number primary key (auto increment),
 driver_id number,
 status number (1 = active, 0 = inactive)
```

On one time in table driver can have one active row for some driver.

Eg.

Allow:

```
 id  driver_id  status
 1   100        0
 2   100        0
 3   100        1
 4   100        0
```

Not allow two row in table where **status = 1** and **driver_id = 100**

```
 id  driver_id  status
 1   100        0
 2   100        0
 3   100        1
 4   100        1
```

**Allow two or more row where is status = 0 but only allow one row where is status = 1**

Comment: What is your try to do this ?

Comment: @VBoka Not allow insert two row for some driver_id where status = 1

Comment: Add your try to the question - the code you have tried and the error you get. And what is the problem with ythe code you have tried.

Comment: Your question is: ""Oracle - Add constraint"" and your try is "Allow two or more row where is status = 0 but only allow one row where is status = 1" ?Is this the way you are adding constriants with code  when using Oracle as your database ??

Comment: Hello @user_odoo, I am sorry but that is not the code. You are just telling us in simple conversation terms what you want to do. The code is something like this: "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT check_constraint_name..."

Comment: @VBoka  Tnx for help but I don't know how describe problem. I'm update my question.  Thanx anyway!

Comment: Hello @user_odoo , I am sorry but I do not believe you. I am asking you to show us your code. Have you tried to create your consraint ? If you have show us how. If you have not then try it. I believe you understand what I am telling you ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional unique constraint in oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317774/conditional-unique-constraint-in-oracle-db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a ***UNIQUE INDEX*** with *conditional* such as

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_chk_driver_status ON t(
                                               CASE 
                                               WHEN status = 1 THEN 
                                                    driver_id 
                                                END
                                               );
```

where `ELSE` case has no sense, since the uniqueness is not needed for `status = 0`