# How to define a custom unique constraint when the entity is "Active"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

Let's say I have an entity Person:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Column(name = "civic_no")
    private String civicNo;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

Here, I need a constraint that ensures the `civic_no` is unique if and only if it is **active**. However, if **not active**, there can be more than one unique `civic_no` without any problem.

One way to achieve this would be to add a constraint at the top that ensures a pair of `civic_no` and `is_active` is unique:

```java
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueCivicNoIfActive", columnNames = { "civic_no", "is_active" }) })
```

However there is a problem with this. Consider I have a person with the `civic_no` =  `555`, then all the below three pairs of entries must be allowed to exist in the database:

```
1. 555 - true
2. 555 - false
3. 555 - false
```

Here, since the entries `2` and `3` are both `inactive` it doesn't matter if the civic number is unique or not, so both of those entries must be allowed. But if I use above constraint, `2` and `3` will not be allowed to co-exist. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the only way to do it is by using indexes. Which database are you using?

Comment: Alright. Right now I am using `Oracle-XE 11`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317774/conditional-unique-constraint-in-oracle-db